# how can i split a string by multiple delimiters and keep the delimiters?

Tags: c#, string, split

i have for exemple this string **`"abc({"`**.
now, i want to split it by the **`"("`** delimiter, and i know i can use String.split for that.
but is there a way i can split if by this symbol but not loss it? like if i used split i would have gotten this **`string[] = { "abc" , "{" }`** and i want **`{ "abc" , "(" , "{" }`**.
 also is there a way to do this with multiple delimiters?

Comment: what if you have this: `abc((({` and you split by `(`, what do you want in the result?

Comment: i always want to keep the delimiters so `{ abc , ( , ( , ( , { }`

Comment: Use `var results = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(s, @"(\()").Where(m=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m));`

Comment: For multiple delimiters, just add them to the regex. To split with `{` and `(`, use `@"([({])"` regex. To split with `abc`, `{` and `(`, use `@"(abc|[{(])"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8yttk7sy(v=vs.110).aspx) with a pattern enclosed with a capturing group.

> If capturing parentheses are used in a `Regex.Split` expression, any captured text is included in the resulting string array.

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/yjP1Am):

```
var s = "abc({";
var results = Regex.Split(s, @"(\()")
    .Where(m=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m))
    .ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
// => abc, (, {
```

The `(\()` regex matches and captures `(` symbol into Capturing group 1, and thus the captured part is also output in the resulting string list.